# Is a Fermi sea a Gaussian state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, fermions

A Fermi sea is of the form

$$ |FS\rangle = \prod_{j=1}^N a_j^\dagger |vac\rangle  .$$

It is very simple. Does it belong to the category of Gaussian states?

Answer (score 5):

Gaussian states are ground and thermal states of Hamiltonians which are quadratic in the fermionic creation and annihilation operators. The state you give is the ground state of the Hamiltonian
$$
H = -\sum a_j^\dagger a_j\ .
$$
Therefore, it is a Gaussian state.